# Printing from Nested Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Learning Python and I have a question about printing from nested dictionaries

```
order = {
    "starter": {1: "Salad", 2: "Soup"},
    "main": {1: ["Burger", "Fries"], 2: ["Steak"]},
    "dessert": {1: ["Ice Cream"], 2: []},
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this

```
print(order["main"][2][0])
```

prints `Steak`

and this

```
print(order["main"][2])
```

prints `['Steak']`

Much appreciated!

Comment: Your logical problem is not with (nested) dictionaries, but with lists. Compare ``print(["abc"])`` with ``print(["abc"][0])``

Answer (score 1):

The value assigned to `order['main'][2]` is a list with a single element, a string `'Steak'`. Therefore, if you print `order['main'][2]`, you get the string representation of the list `['Steak']`.

This might become more clear if we look at some different examples:

```
>>> print(order['main'])
{1: ['Burger', 'Fries'], 2: ['Steak']}
>>> print(order['main'][1])
['Burger', 'Fries']
>>> print(order['main'][1][0])
Burger
>>> print(order['main'][1][1])
Fries
>>> print(order['main'][2])
['Steak']
>>> print(order['main'][2][0])
Steak
```